# split_on_silence modify the original audio

Tags: python, audio

after using `split_on_silence` the audio transform :
for exemple : 
Original : hello, my name is John.
chunks : 
chunk1 : ell
chunk2 : name

my code :

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("videofr.wav")
#split track where silence is 0.2 seconds or more and get chunks
chunks = split_on_silence(song,
    # must be silent for at least 0.2 seconds or 200 ms
    min_silence_len=200,
                            )
cpt = 0
print(len(song))
for i,chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    print((chunk))
    print(len(chunk))
    cpt = cpt + 1
    chunk.export(".//chunk{0}.wav".format(i), format="wav")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try varying `min_silence_len` and `silence_thresh` values to get as close to actual silence duration and dbFS level as possible.
for e.g.

```
chunks = split_on_silence(song,
    # must be silent for at least 0.2 seconds or 200 ms
    min_silence_len=200,

    # consider it silent if quieter than -16 dBFS
    silence_thresh=-16
```

You can verify actual values by loading your file in `audacity` and checking for silence duration and amplitude at the end of sentences.